# Requires valid signature error, facebook api

Tags: facebook

i'am using this example

http://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/examples/jquery/login.html

works fine ,
but when i change query part to read my statuses i am getting exception

Requires valid signature

for instance this query

select message from status where uid=myuid

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

It means you need a valid access token.

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/

You can see on that page:

> In addition to the access token (the access_token parameter), the
>   response contains the number of seconds until the token expires (the
>   expires parameter). Once the token expires, you will need to re-run
>   the steps above to generate a new code and access_token, although if
>   the user has already authorized your app, they will not be prompted to
>   do so again.